# Attribute table will not open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I cannot view any of my attribute tables.  I am able to click "Open Attribute Table", but the table will not show up. I am only able to see the following. It looks like there is a blank table.  However, even if I click on that table, it does not show up on my monitors.

[image]

Comment: Have you knocked it off and on again?

Comment: Do you have any attributes at all? Check in `Layer Properties > Tab Fields`

Comment: What type of data: shapefile? Geopackage? File geodatabase? Something else???

Comment: You may want to check that it's not open under the main QGIS window (just minimise it) or outside of the screen area (often there is a very thin part barely visible at the edge of the screen that you can grab and expend). If not you may try to check the "Open attribute table as docked window" tickbox (go to Setting > Option : data source tab)

Comment: **1.** Click on the 2nd window shown in the image **2.** Press `Alt+Space` **3.** Press `M` (shortcut for the Move option of the window) **4.** And move the mouse. You probably will see that the window moves with the mouse cursor in your screen.